# What feats should I take with my Constructor Psion?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, optimization, psionics

I've been playing a Metacreativity (Constructor) Psion for a few months, and I'm worried that my feat selection is not very good.  I've been told by multiple sources that some of the feats that I've taken (like Psionic Body) are really bad, but I don't really know what I should replace them with.  I have access to Psionic Reformation, so changing my feats around is trivial.

My DM doesn't allow 3.5 content, everything has to be from a Paizo Pathfinder product, with the exception of the Dreamscarred Press psionics stuff, which is also allowed.  We are not using retraining rules, so the only things I can change around are the things that Psychic Reformation can change.

My character is a level 13 [Psion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/classes/psion) with the [Metacreativity](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/classes/psion/psionic-disciplines/metacreativity) ([Constructor](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/classes/psion/psionic-disciplines/metacreativity/constructor)) discipline.  I am also Mythic Tier 3.  I am an Archmage.  My GM has ruled that psionics counts as arcane magic for the purposes of Mythic, so anything that an arcane caster can get from there, I can probably get.  If there are any questions about specific rulings that may apply, let me know and I will answer them.

My current feat set is:

- [Additional Traits](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/additional-traits) (I use this to get [Spark of Creation](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/magic-traits/spark-of-creation-magic) and [Psigifted](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/psionic-alternate-rules/psionic-traits/psigifted)(Astral Construct), to raise my maximum augment level by 1.  My GM doesn't allow traits without a feat.)
- [Persistent Power](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/feats/persistent-power-metapsionic)
- [Selective Power](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/feats/selective-power-metapsionic)
- [Advanced Constructs](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/feats/advanced-constructs-psionic)
- [Power Penetration](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/feats/power-penetration-psionic)
- [Greater Power Penetration](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/feats/greater-power-penetration-psionic)
- [Boost Construct](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/feats/boost-construct-psionic) (Constructor bonus feat)
- [Overchannel](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/feats/overchannel-psionic) (Psion bonus feat)
- [Psionic Body](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/feats/psionic-body-psionic) (Psion bonus feat)
- [Psionic Meditation](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/feats/psionic-meditation-psionic) (Psion bonus feat)
- [Dual Path (Heirophant)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-feats/dual-path-mythic) (Mythic. I use this to get Mighty Summons, which lets me summon [Agile](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-monsters/mythic-simple-templates) constructs.)
- [Spell Penetration (Mythic)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-feats/spell-penetration-mythic) (Mythic.  Applies to powers as well.)

I haven't chosen my 13th level feat yet.  What else could I take, and what should I replace?

Comment: Answer in answers please...

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I see that you're trying to be two things, and this might be a bit of splitting point on your build, so I have what I hope is a good and sensible option.

**Continue being split over two objective, but do it smarter**

You use reformation to Psionic Body, Additional Traits, Power Penetration, Great Power Penetration, Spell Penetration (Mythic), and Persist Power for [Psicrystal Affinity](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/feats/psicrystal-affinity-psionic), [Psicrystal Containment](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/feats/psicrystal-containment-psionic), [Burrowing Power](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/feats/burrowing-power-metapsionic), [Delay Power](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/feats/delay-power-metapsionic), [Enlarge Power](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/feats/enlarge-power-metapsionic), and [Extend Power](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/feats/extend-power-metapsionic). Additionally you reformation away all your offensive powers that allow Power/Spell Resistance away for alternatives that don't allow this defense.

This will let you start fights with a Extended Astral Construct, and let you manifest your blasting power in a more versatile way. While it does lower your options of powers to use, you can use your good selection of Metapsionic feats to make powers fit the situation, and you can apply two of them if you need to, as your glowing rock buddy can hold some of your psionic focus for you.

Comment: Doesn't Extending the Astral Construct make it one level lower that it would otherwise be?  Wouldn't it be better to make my construct stronger, than longer lasting?  And wouldn't getting rid of my traits also make my construct less powerful, through a lower manifester level?

Comment: It would be weaker yes... but you are going to be able to over channel to the point that even an Extended Astral Construct will have C menu options, so it won't ever be notably weaker then the others. In two levels, you won't need to over channel to do so. If you like, you can wait on Enlarge power, to hold onto Additional Traits for level 14, the last time it's going to be reasonably effective, as you can use reformation to make yourself into a crafter anytime you have the down time to warrant it.

Extended AC would be for the long fights of course, not fighting one or two high CR foes.

Comment: Your other option is to continue to spend feats for limited yields. Remember, with Psychic reformation you can tweak your feats from level to level to stay optimal. 8th level constructs aren't worth the opportunity costs if you can spend those 2 power points in something like extended.